# How do I insert a string into another string after a specific letter?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nsstring

I'm storing heights in my database as 62 or 511 instead of 6 ft 2 or 5 ft 11.

**This is how I prepare the string that will be saved:**

```
    let height = 6 ft 2
    let myNewString = height.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ft ", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    println(myNewString) // 62
```

What I'd like to do is now do the opposite thing when displaying back the data from the database.

So I'd like to take the returned "62" from the database and insert this string " ft " into it. My aim is to end up with "6 ft 2" to display on the app.

How can I do this?

I want to avoid storing two columns dedicated to height in my database. I only know how to concatenate strings but this isn't exactly concatenating a string. I am inserting it into an existing string.

I'd appreciate an efficient way to do this. Been looking around for a while now and can't seem to find my solution.

Thanks for your time.

**Update:**

After reading comments I'm wondering if it would be better to add a decimal point after the first char in string e.g. 4.2, 4.10, 5.4, 5.11, 6.2 etc

```
let height = 6 ft 2
let myNewString = height.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ft ", withString: ".", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
println(myNewString) // 6.2
```

Comment: Your representation is ambiguous. `111` could be `11 ft 1` or `1 ft 11`.

Comment: min age is 4 ft 0 and max is 7 ft 11 @MartinR

Comment: Ohh! I see what you're saying. I totally missed that. Back to the drawing board for me. Maybe I can add a decimal point after the first char

Comment: It's not ambiguous. Given the height range you stated, the first digit is always the feet and the remaining digits (if any) are the inches.

Comment: Sure, if the feet are restricted to one digit. That wasn't apparent (to me) from the question.

Comment: Rather than being more clever with format, just store it in inches. You'll even save space, if that's the goal, by using a 1-byte int rather than a three-byte string.

Comment: You can format it localized using [`NSLengthFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/NSLengthFormatter_Class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be a better idea to store the height purely in inches (e.g. store 74 for 6'2").

Anyway:

```
    let input = "62"
    let feet = (input as NSString).substringToIndex(1)
    let inches = (input as NSString).substringFromIndex(1)
    let output = "\(feet) ft \(inches)"
```

If you don't like the use of `NSString`, you can avoid it this way:

```
    let input = "62";
    let feet = input.substringToIndex(input.startIndex.successor())
    let inches = input.substringFromIndex(input.startIndex.successor())
    let output = "\(feet) ft \(inches)"
```

Comment: I was thinking of storing as 4'0" but the reason I didn't was because I was under the impression I wouldn't be able to use that format with parse query conditions e.g. query where height is greater than ..... and less than. I thought this would only work with integers only. But I'm in parse now and have manually edited some fields and clicked the column header and the fields have been put in correct order (lowest height to highest) so guessing it will work in code too. So I can just store as e.g. 6'2" and display this way also.

Comment: Are you sure that `5'10"` will sort after `5'2"`?

Answer (score 2):

Swift’s `String` conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`, which has a `splice` method – `splice` allows you to insert a collection into another collection.  Since strings are collections, that means you can write:

```
var height = "62"
if !height.isEmpty {
    height.splice(" ft ", atIndex: height.startIndex.successor())
} // height is now "6 ft 2"
```

Alternatively if you know you only want the first character before the “ft” you can do:

```
let height = "62"
if let feet = first(height) {
    let inches = dropFirst(height)
    let heightWithFt = "\(feet) ft \(inches)"
}
```